# Definition - limit of a sequence - uses "rank"?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, terminology, definition

I have the following definition in my book, and was confused as to the context of the word "rank" here.
The definition is as follows:

A sequence $(u_n)_{n∈N}$ has limit $l ∈ R$ as $n → ∞$ (we also say “converges to $l$ as $n → ∞$”) if, for any $ε > 0$, there exists a rank $N_ε ∈ N$ such that, for any $n ≥ N_ε$, $|u_n − l| ≤ ε$...

I understand everything except for the portion "there exists a rank $N_ε ∈ N$".

What exactly does this line mean to convey?

Comment: Source?${{{}}}$

Comment: I've never seen the use of "rank" in this context before, but I would rewrite it as "there exists a natural number $N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq N_\epsilon$, we have $|u_n-\ell|\leq \epsilon$".

Comment: Source - lecture notes from my professor. Will raise it up in recitation I guess then.

I agree Hayden, this was my understanding of the definition, which I read in Abbott's analysis. My prof bases his notes off that book but leaves some things out and adds some things of his own.

Comment: Does he ever repeat the term 'rank'?

Comment: I seem to recall that John Cagnol who taught/teaches the "An introduction to Functional Analysis" course on Coursera used rank in this context. Since the course is closed at the moment, I cannot verify it. But Hayden is right, that the more common and equivalent definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: @GitGud for infinite limit and cauchy limit... so Can't really gather what context. I will ask on thursday and update this thread if anyone is interested.